# Laravel airlock / sanctum auth check

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-sanctum, laravel-airlock

How I can get or check auth user without auth:sanctum. I try get auth user `auth()->user()` from guest route but I get only `null`. And yes I pass token but still get null nested user. But if I try with route inside `auth:sanctum` all ok.

Comment: please include all relevant code and a minimum example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need use auth('sanctum')->user(); or auth('sanctum')->check();

Comment: Also, you can modify your `auth` config by changing the `driver` value of `guards.api`. This way it will be the default guard on all API routes.